# OnPropertyChanged is being called twice for a bindable property

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindable

In Xamarin Forms, I created a bindable property like so:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItem", typeof(MyItem), typeof(MyGrid), default(MyItem));

public MyItem SelectedItem
{
     get { return (MyItem)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}
```

Here's my constructor:

```
public MyView()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
   if (propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName == "SelectedItem")
   {
       // called twice
   }
}
```

Can somebody explain why property changed event is firing **twice**? If I create a changed handler in the definition of the bindable property, then the handler is called **once**.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItem", typeof(MyItem), typeof(MyGrid), default(MyItem), null, SelectedItemChanged);
```

I have noticed the issue exists only in code-behind. If I set the property directly in XAML, property changed event fires **once**.

Answer (score 3):

We don't really have enough information to answer this question with certainty, but I can speculate.

Without seeing your `SetValue` method, my assumption would be that it lacks a short circuit, e.g. "don't do anything if the new value and the old value are the same".

Then my second assumption would be that the control that is being bound to this property is setting it (after being bound). This can happen with list-type controls when `SelectedItem` is bound.

The resulting chain of events might be something like:

1. Code sets property
2. PropertyChanged event is fired
3. Binding sets the value on a control
4. Control reports it's value has been changed, and two-way binding sets the value on the ViewModel again
5. The lack of a short circuit causes the PropertyChanged event to be raised again
6. The binding sets the value on the control again (to the same value as before)
7. The control does not report a change, because it's property is short-circuited properly

My guess is that if you were to short circuit your setter (by checking against the existing value and bailing out if they are the same) this behavior would stop.

Comment: I am facing same issue, the problem is that I can not set check with new value and old value because it's keep on changing from true to false and vice versa. So this is not the correct solution.